# To get an empty value in ViewModel when DatePickerTextBox is made empty on Datepicker control

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime, mvvm, datepicker

I have a DatePicker whose `SelectedDate` is bound to a CLR property with two-way binding in ViewModel named `VMStartDate`. When UI opens, the default date displayed on Date picker is today's date.

**View.xaml**

```
<DatePicker Width="160" Height="35" 
            SelectedDate="{Binding Path=VMStartDate,Mode=TwoWay, 
                            TargetNullValue={x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}}">
  <DatePicker.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePickerTextBox}">
      <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate>
            <TextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox" Height="28" BorderBrush="Transparent" 
                     VerticalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                     BorderThickness="0" FontSize="14" 
                     Text="{Binding Path=SelectedDate, StringFormat='dd/MM/yyyy',
                       RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DatePicker}}}" 
                     Validation.ErrorTemplate="{x:Null}" />
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
  </DatePicker.Resources>
</DatePicker>
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```
private DateTime _VMStartDate;

public DateTime VMStartDate
{
    get { return _VMStartDate; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _VMStartDate, value); }
}
```

I want the `DatePicker` to display an empty string until user picks a date or deletes it.

Comment: Shouldn't making the property nullable do that? Memory doesn't confirm for me and I'm not in a position to test to confirm, but intuition says if you  do public DateTime? VmStartDate {get; set;} you should be good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As gilliduck suggested in the comment, making the `DateTime` nullable, will give you the desired effect. That is the method I have been using myself extensively to have the default of a DateTime be an empty cell. With that, your Property will look like this.

```
private DateTime? _VMStartDate = null;

public DateTime? VMStartDate
{
    get { return _VMStartDate; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _VMStartDate, value); }
}
```